# Typewriter split multiple classes from one c# file into their own file ts files

Tags: c#, typescript, auto-generate, typewriter

I have one c# file called FooBar.cs with two classes in it. These classes cannot be moved into their own separate C# files (as much as I would like to).

```
[ExportToTypescript("Foo.ts")]
public class Foo
{
    String prop1 { get; set; }
    String prop2 { get; set; }
}

[ExportToTypescript("Bar.ts")]
public class Bar
{
    String prop1 { get; set; }
    String prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use typewriter to generate two .ts files from this one .cs file.

I can add a parameter to the constructor of the attribute to take the filename of the typescript file I want to generate, but I can't find a way of coding the .tst config to create a file per class. Is this possible?